# C++ stable_partition Compiler Error

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to extend an example I found in Koenig and Moo's "Accelerated C++." I've got the following code which attempts to split a vector into two partitions.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct MyClass {
    int* MyInt;
    MyClass() : MyInt(NULL) {}
};

struct AnalyzeMemOps {
    vector<MyClass> AllMyClassRecords;  // Where I keep the MyClass instances
    bool sameBaseReg(MyClass m);
    vector<MyClass> splitBySameBase(vector<MyClass>& main);
    AnalyzeMemOps() {}
};

// Predicate function for stable_partition
bool AnalyzeMemOps::sameBaseReg(MyClass m) {
    return true;
}

vector<MyClass> AnalyzeMemOps::splitBySameBase(vector<MyClass>& main) {
    vector<MyClass>::iterator it =
        stable_partition(main.begin(), main.end(), sameBaseReg);    // Error is here
    vector<MyClass> sameBases(it, main.end());
    main.erase(it, main.end());

    // Print results
    cout << "Split By Same Base: Returning SameBase Instrs\n";
    for (vector<MyClass>::iterator i = sameBases.begin(); i != sameBases.end(); ++i) {
        cout << "  " << i->MyInt << "\n";
    }

    return sameBases;
}

int main() {
    AnalyzeMemOps AMCR;

    MyClass m;
    AMCR.AllMyClassRecords.push_back(m);
    AMCR.AllMyClassRecords.push_back(m);
    AMCR.AllMyClassRecords.push_back(m);

    vector<MyClass> t = AMCR.splitBySameBase(AMCR.AllMyClassRecords);
}
```

I get an error when I attempt to compile this file with g++:

```
Tile.cpp: In member function \u2018std::vector<MyClass, std::allocator<MyClass> > AnalyzeMemOps::splitBySameBase(std::vector<MyClass, std::allocator<MyClass> >&)\u2019:
Tile.cpp:26: error: no matching function for call to \u2018stable_partition(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<MyClass*, std::vector<MyClass, std::allocator<MyClass> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<MyClass*, std::vector<MyClass, std::allocator<MyClass> > >, <unresolved overloaded function type>)\u2019
/usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_algo.h:1864: note: candidates are: _BIter std::stable_partition(_BIter, _BIter, _Predicate) [with _BIter = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<MyClass*, std::vector<MyClass, std::allocator<MyClass> > >, _Predicate = bool (AnalyzeMemOps::*)(MyClass)]
make: *** [a.out] Error 1
```

Obviously this is a toy example, but I've checked the function prototypes and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `sameBaseReg` is a member function of `AnalyzeMemOps`.  You can't use it like an ordinary non-member function because it can only be called on an object.

If you have a modern compiler that supports C++0x, C++ TR1, or if you have Boost handy, you can use `bind` to bind the pointer to member function to the `this` object:

```
std::bind(&AnalyzeMemOps::sameBaseReg, this, std::placeholders::_1)
```

In the current C++ standard library, the `<functional>` library has `std::mem_fun`,  `std::bind1st`, and other functions that can help with this, but they are an absolute beating to use effectively.

Comment: How "bad form" would it be to make the splitBySameBase member function call a non-member function version of sameBaseReg? I just discovered that if sameBaseReg is in the same namespace, it works fine.

Comment: @Zeke:  If it doesn't need to be a member function, you should definitely make it a non-member function.  If it doesn't need access to any of the private or protected member variables of your class, it should be a non-member function.

Comment: Well, when put like that, the entire splitBySameBase function doesn't even have to be in the AnalyzeMemOp class. I had all the functions in the class for organization purposes, but I guess they don't need to be member functions at all! Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Zeke:  Herb Sutter wrote a series of articles on "The Interface Principle," discussing how best to leverage non-member functions; I highly recommend reading them, they are terrific articles: http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill02.htm http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill08.htm http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/084.htm (there may be a few more in the series if you search around; those are just the three I remember).

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use `mem_fun` to turn the member function into an function object, then use `bind1st` to supply the `this` pointer.

I was never particularly successful getting this stuff to work on a regular basis (the standard library algorithms seem to be mainly designed for use with freestanding functions or hand-written predicate classes), but something like this should do the trick:

```
vector<MyClass>::iterator it =
    stable_partition(main.begin(),
                     main.end(),
                     bind1st(mem_fun(&AnalyzeMemOps::sameBaseReg),
                             this));
```

`mem_fun` gives you back a function object that takes two arguments, the first being the object to invoke `mem_fun`'s member function on, and the second being the single argument to the member function.

`bind1st` takes a function object that takes two arguments, and returns you a new one that takes one argument, which when invoked via `operator()` will call the original function object with the `bind1st`'s argument as its first argument and the supplied argument as the second.

The end result is that a new function object is created, that takes one argument, and that will call `this->sameBaseReg`, passing in the supplied argument.